# Unity DXR Reflections Not Working Properly

Tags: unity, rendering, raytracing, realtime

When I use RTX powered reflections in Unity HDRP+DXR it reflects a limited distance of non emitting materials, It means if I add emission to the mesh in distance its emission gets reflected but still not default surface of it. Also the following issue only happens when using Point or Spot lights, Directional lights are fine, It seems unity ray-tracing does not include the light in distance.

**Edit :** This can be fixed by using `Light Clusters` I will answer this to my question in 24h, Still problem 2 exists.

I made a simple project which demonstrate the issue : https://github.com/CycloneRing/RTX-Issue

Problem Number 2 :

**Also when meshes are close to the edges they are not visible in reflections as well.**

Here's a picture of issue in the RTX-Issue project at repo :
[image: Image1]

Now when camera gets closer to the boxes we can see lights are reflected :
[image: Image2]

How can I fix it?